# HERE requests how to assign multiple values to a key in params

Tags: python, python-requests, here-api, here-fleet-telematics

I am trying to obtain the best route using [FindSequence API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/api-reference-findsequence.html) for *n* number of destinations. Here is my code:

```
URL5 = "https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json"
params5 = {
    "apiKey": my_key,
    "departure":"2014-11-11T16:52:00Z",
    "start": first,
    "destinations": [i for i in f], 
    "end": last,
    "mode": "fastest;truck;traffic:enabled" # To enable traffic, "departure" parameter must be included
}

res5 = requests.get(url = URL5, params = params5)
data5 = res5.json()
```

Where `first` and `last` are strings with name of the destination;lat,long

- `first = "HARDIE'S MOBILE HOME PARK; 30.44126118, -86.6240656099999"`
- `last = "HOUSTON PARK MOBILE HOME PARK; 30.4424195300001, -86.64733076"`

And `f` is a list with the other points the route must pass before arriving to the `last` destination.

```
f = ['CRESTVIEW RV PARK; 30.7190163500001, -86.5716222299999',
 'HOMESTEAD TRAILER PARK; 30.5115772500001, -86.4628417499999']
```

However, it looks like it is just "reading" the `first` and `last` data points and is completely ignoring the other two destinations from the list `f`. This is the output I am getting:

```
[{'id': "HARDIE'S MOBILE HOME PARK",
  'lat': 30.44126118,
  'lng': -86.6240656099999,
  'sequence': 0,
  'estimatedArrival': None,
  'estimatedDeparture': '2014-11-11T16:52:00Z',
  'fulfilledConstraints': []},
 {'id': 'HOUSTON PARK MOBILE HOME PARK',
  'lat': 30.4424195300001,
  'lng': -86.64733076,
  'sequence': 1,
  'estimatedArrival': '2014-11-11T17:02:30Z',
  'estimatedDeparture': None,
  'fulfilledConstraints': []}]
```

The desired output must look like this:

```
[{'id': "HARDIE'S MOBILE HOME PARK",
  'lat': 30.44126118,
  'lng': -86.6240656099999,
  'sequence': 0,
  'estimatedArrival': None,
  'estimatedDeparture': '2014-11-11T16:52:00Z',
  'fulfilledConstraints': []},
 {'id': 'CRESTVIEW RV PARK',
  'lat': 30.719016,
  'lng': -86.571622,
  'sequence': 1,
  'estimatedArrival': None,
  'estimatedDeparture': '2014-11-11T17:37:08Z',
  'fulfilledConstraints': []},
 {'id': 'HOMESTEAD TRAILER PARK',
  'lat': 30.511577,
  'lng': -86.462842,
  'sequence': 2,
  'estimatedArrival': None,
  'estimatedDeparture': '2014-11-11T18:07:25Z',
  'fulfilledConstraints': []},
 {'id': 'HOUSTON PARK MOBILE HOME PARK',
  'lat': 30.4424195300001,
  'lng': -86.64733076,
  'sequence': 3,
  'estimatedArrival': '2014-11-11T18:43:24Z',
  'estimatedDeparture': None,
  'fulfilledConstraints': []}]
```

And that desired output can be obtained using this code:

```
URL3 = "https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json"
params3 = {
    "apiKey": here_api_key,
    "departure":"2014-11-11T16:52:00Z",
    "start": first,
    "destination1": "CRESTVIEW RV PARK;30.719016, -86.571622",
    "destination2": "HOMESTEAD TRAILER PARK;30.511577, -86.462842",
    "end": last,
    "mode": "fastest;truck;traffic:enabled" # To enable traffic, "departure" parameter must be included
}

res3 = requests.get(url = URL3, params = params3)
data3 = res3.json()
```

Although the code above works just fine, it is not the best approach since I need to pass from than just 2 destinations. I am new at HERE APIs so If anyone knows how to do that I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can verify in the [FindSequence API documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/api-reference-findsequence.html) there is no such thing as a `destinations` parameter, so it is totally understandable that in your 1st example the route does not visit these destinations. So you must pass `destination1`, `destination2` etc parameters.

If you want to automatically create these parameters in your Dictionary, as I am not a Python user, please search in StackOverflow to find out how, that are many answers that can help you, for example:

[programmatically generate key and values to put in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772151/programmatically-generate-key-and-values-to-put-in-python-dictionary)

[Create dictionary where keys are variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818733/create-dictionary-where-keys-are-variable-names)